# Php Mysql Query is not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have to calculate profit from two different tables Expense and Income. There is no such relationship between two tables.I have used following mysql query but now working.

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(DATE ) FROM (
        SELECT DATE FROM expense_tbl
        UNION ALL
        SELECT `date` FROM income_tbl
        ) 
    AS u GROUP BY MONTH(DATE);


Table: Income

date            amount

12/12/2016      25,000
01/01/2017      20,000
05/01/2017      2000


Table Expense

date            amount

24/12/2016      20,000
30/12/2017      1000
10/01/2017      12000



Expected Output

Period      Income      Expense     Profit

December    25,000      21,000      4000
January     22,000      12,000      10000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   SELECT MONTH(DATE ),
           sum(case when u.srce = 'i' then amount else 0 end) as Income,
           sum(case when u.srce = 'e' then amount else 0 end) as Expense,
           sum(case when u.srce = 'i' then amount else 0 end) -
           sum(case when u.srce = 'e' then amount else 0 end) as Profit
        FROM
       (
        SELECT 'e' as srce,DATE, amount FROM expense
        UNION 
        SELECT 'i',`date`, amount FROM income
    ) AS u
        GROUP BY MONTH(DATE);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select monthname(income.date) as monthname,income.amount,
expense.amount,sum(income.amount)-sum(expense.amount) as profit from 
income join expense on month(income.date) = month(expense.date)
group by month(expense.date);
```